# How to get a constant value in milliseconds of the last bar

Tags: pine-script

I would like to get a constant value in milliseconds of the last bar shown. At the moment I'm using the "time" variable but that is not getting me a constant value because it's taking also in consideration the previous bars, so the plot looks like a slope upwards.

If I use ta.valuewhen(barstate.islast, time, 0) that shows the value in milliseconds only on the last bar, but not on the previous ones. Is there a way?

I'm trying to build an indicator which displays a "true" condition 24 hours before the last bar is shown. So for example if it's afternoon 16:30 I would like to do a plotshape on the previous day at 16:30, would there be a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

When you request the data with 'ta.valuewhen' it will return the data of the confirmed candle, even if you specify exactly the seconds and milliseconds it will return the values ​​(olhc and plots values) that it had when closing that candle, even if you extract the data of the candle you are on will cause your indicator/strategy to change values ​​every second because the candle is not closed

And for the 24 hour indicator you can't make plots on previous candles either, the code is executed once each candle closes, and if the condition is not true at the close of that candle it will not make any plot and you will not be able to change that, the only thing you could do would be to establish at what time you want to make the plot and execute it from there

It would be something like this

```
tHour = input.int(16, minval=0,  maxval=23, title="Hour")
tMin  = input.int(30, minval=0,  maxval=59, title="Minute")

validTime = ( hour == tHour and minute == tMin ) ? true : false

plotshape(validTime)

//Also you can agregate seconds if you work in seconds timeframe
```

Comment: Thank you Humberto for your reply, much appreciated.
I believe "time" "Note that this variable returns the timestamp based on the time of the bar's open" shouldn't change every second.
And regarding the 24hour indicator, there must be a way maybe with a loop function, but I'm not expert enough to do it. Let's see if anyone skilled can give us a hand :) 
Thank you guys!